# Bitcoin was sent to my wallet 7 days ago but it has not reflect in the wallet

Tags: blockchain

I checked the bitcoin explorer to check if the bitcoin is in and Yes it is but it stays unspent but it has not reflect in the wallet of the main address for 7days now

d325c9a20df855cb1a051d6ed1cee6aea795f2cdd3befaa913855cd1d6128532

This is the transaction id

Comment: Which bitcoin wallet are you using?

Comment: If you need more help, please give us more information about what wallet you're using, whether you see nothing or an unconfirmed transaction in the wallet, and what happened after trying the suggestions I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction is indeed confirmed on the network. This means that either your wallet failed to pick it up, or it paid a different address than you think.

1. Check whether the address that the transaction credits indeed belongs to your wallet. Verify that the address is not a "watch-only" address.
2. Check if your wallet is out of sync. Many wallets have a way to "rescan" or "resync" the blockchain. You can probably find instructions by searching for " out of sync".

Comment: What if my wallet failed to pick it up, will it still be spendable after sometime

Comment: Yes, the transaction records are in the blockchain, if the transaction did go to your address, it's just a matter of your wallet properly reading this shared global state.