# My bitcoin hasn't been received for good 10days now

Tags: transactions

I have sent my first Transaction from a bitcoin machine and waiting for it to arrive at another address but when i click on the Transaction ID of the addresses is Unspent? It only required 3 Confirmations but is now 115? Where is my bitcoin and how do i receive it?

15AwkRrfooSwFiegrVvMk8HaGwE8h83Kk1

Comment: Whoever knows the private key for address `15Aw...3Kk1` has 0.003 BTC available to spend. It was received 11 days ago in transaction `d325...8532`.

Comment: What software are you using to receive? Also could you clarify how doing the two things I suggested on your prior question https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/105342/5406 went?